# QT signal and slot pass variable to another form

Tags: c++, forms, qt, connect, qt-signals

iam googling for 10hours and nothing helped me.

I have two form(.ui) in QT.

first mainwindow.ui - i have here table and when user click on table row, it send value of this table row to

second zobraz.ui

mainwindow.h

```
signals:
    void sendIntData(int data);
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
void MainWindow::on_tableView_doubleClicked(const QModelIndex &index)
{
zobraz1 = new zobraz(this);

zobraz1->show();

int o=index.row();
QString oo=QString::number(o);
ui->textEdit->setText(oo);

emit sendIntData(o);

connect(this, SIGNAL(sendIntData(int)),zobraz1, SLOT(setIntData(int)));

}
```

zobraz.h

```
public slots:
    void setIntData(int data);

public:
    explicit zobraz(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~zobraz();

private:
    Ui::zobraz *ui;
    int indexx;

};
```

zobraz.cpp

```
void zobraz::setIntData(int data)
{
    indexx=data;

} 

zobraz::zobraz(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::zobraz)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QString poradiee=QString::number(indexx);
    ui->label_2->setText(poradiee);
```

Thanks a lot for answer, i dont know what is bad.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test your code, but one problem is related to connection: connections must be done BEFORE emitting signals. So you should change these line:

```
emit sendIntData(o);
connect(this, SIGNAL(sendIntData(int)),zobraz1, SLOT(setIntData(int)));
```

to:

```
connect(this, SIGNAL(sendIntData(int)),zobraz1, SLOT(setIntData(int)));
emit sendIntData(o);
```

Comment: I tried, still nothing, when i click on specified row in table, it still doesnt send int variable with row number to zobraz.cpp label_2.

it is compiled but connection doesnt work, variable "indexx" is not the same as variable "o"

Comment: Sorry, I can't test your code now. To debug your code try to add qDebug()<<"function called";  inside on_tableView_doubleClicked to check if it's called.

Answer (score 0):

problem vas at setintdata. It should look like this. But IDK why.

```
void zobraz::setIntData(int data)
{

    QString poradieee=QString::number(data+1);
    ui->label_2->setText(poradieee);

    indexx=data;

}
```

Comment: Because calling `indexx=data;` only updates the content of `indexx`. There's no reason for the label to get updated because you are assigning a new value to a variable.